# Adding errorbars to horizontal barplot in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I would really appreciate help with my little R problem from the community here. I have searched everywhere but have not found a solution yet.

My data looks like this:

```
trait2 <- c('A','B','C','D')
rg <- c (0.5480, 0.4801, 0.2805, -0.2480)
se <- c(0.0495, 0.0908, 0.0548, 0.0957)

trait2   rg      se
A       0.5480  0.0495
B       0.4801  0.0908
C       0.2805  0.0548
D       -0.2480  0.0957
```

And I ploted a basic barplot using this code:

```
barplot1 <- barplot(data$rg,
main="correlation between traits",
xlab="rG",  
border="blue", 
las=1, 
horiz=TRUE, 
names.arg=data$trait2, 
cex.names=0.5,
xlim=range(-0.4,0.6,0.1) )
```

which works fine:
[image: barplot]

But I am having trouble with the error bars using this code:

```
arrows(barplot1, 
   data$rg- data$se,
   data$rg+ data$se,
   lwd= 1.5,angle=90,code=3,length=0.05)
```

Errorbars appear, but not where they are supposed to appear:
[image: errobars]

It is probably very simple but I would be very greatful if someone could help me.
Best, Aron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `horiz = FALSE`, then your `arrows` code chunk should be

```
arrows(x0 = barplot1, 
       y0 = data$rg - data$se,
       x1 = barplot1,
       y1 = data$rg + data$se,
       lwd= 1.5,angle=90,code=3,length=0.05)
```

However, since `horiz = TRUE`, you need to switch the positions of `x0`, `y0`, `x1`, `y1`. The full code for doing this in base R is:

```
barplot1 <- barplot(data$rg,
                    main="correlation between traits",
                    xlab="rG",  
                    border="blue", 
                    las=1, 
                    horiz = TRUE,
                    names.arg=data$trait2, 
                    cex.names=0.5,
                    xlim=range(-0.4,0.6,0.1))


segments(data$rg - data$se, barplot1, data$rg + data$se , barplot1,
         lwd = 1.5)

arrows(data$rg - data$se, barplot1, data$rg + data$se, barplot1, 
       lwd = 1.5, angle = 90,
       code = 3, length = 0.05)
```

[image]

---

It is easier to do this in `ggplot2`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(trait2, rg)) + geom_col(color = "blue") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = rg - se, ymax = rg + se), width = 0.3) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried so many different versions of the arrow function, but that one just was not among them, though it seems so logical now. Thank you again!